# Getting the path to the newest file in a directory with f=$(cd dir | ls -t | head) not honoring "dir"

Tags: bash, sh

I would like to get file (zip file) from path with this part of code `file=$(cd '/path_to_zip_file' | ls -t | head -1)`. Instead that I got my .sh file in directory where I am running this file.

Why I can't file from `/path_to_zip_file`

Below is my code in .sh file

```
file=$(cd '/path_to_zip_file' | ls -t | head -1)
last_modified=`stat -c "%Y" $file`;
current=`date +%s`
echo $file

if [ $(($current-$last_modified)) -gt 86400 ]; then
        echo 'Mail'
else
        echo 'No Mail'
fi;
```

Comment: `cd ... | whatever` pipes the *output* of the `cd` command into `whatever`. `cd` has no output. (Moreover, because different pieces of a pipeline run in different processes, the `ls` is happening in your original directory).

Comment: See [BashFAQ #99](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/099), *How do I get the latest (or oldest) file from a directory?* -- parsing `ls` [is unsafe](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were going to use `ls -t | head -1` (which you shouldn't), the `cd` would need to be corrected as a prior command (happening *before* `ls` takes place), not a pipeline component (running *parallel with* `ls`, with its stdout connected to `ls`'s stdin):

```
set -o pipefail # otherwise, a failure of ls is ignored so long as head succeeds
file=$(cd '/path_to_zip_file' && ls -t | head -1)
```

A better-practice approach might look like:

```
newest_file() {
  local result=$1; shift                      # first, treat our first arg as latest
  while (( $# )); do                          # as long as we have more args...
    [[ $1 -nt $result ]] && result=$1         # replace "result" if they're newer
    shift                                     # then take them off the argument list
  done
  [[ -e $result || -L $result ]] || return 1  # fail if no file found
  printf '%s\n' "$result"                     # more reliable than echo
}

newest=$(newest_file /path/to/zip/file/*)
newest=${newest##*/}  ## trim the path to get only the filename
printf 'Newest file is: %s\n' "$newest"
```

To understand the `${newest##*/}` syntax, see [the bash-hackers' wiki on parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).

For more on why using `ls` in scripts (except for output displayed to humans) is dangerous, see [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Bot [BashFAQ #99](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/099), *How do I get the latest (or oldest) file from a directory?* -- and [BashFAQ #3](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) (*How can I sort or compare files based on some metadata attribute (newest / oldest modification time, size, etc)?*) have useful discussion on the larger context in which this question was asked.

Comment: thanks a lot for great answer, I got an error `1539089164-: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "-")`. I think problem is with file in this line `last_modified=`stat -c "%Y" $file`;`

Comment: Looks like `$(($current-$last_modified))` didn't parse because `last_modified` was empty. Did you run `last_modified=$(stat -c %Y "$file")`?

Comment: to what extent does "printf is more reliable than echo" apply even to bash-specific scripts?

Comment: ...btw, note the quoting there -- you **don't** need quotes around the `%Y`, but you *do* need quotes around the `$file`; without them, the filename is string-split and glob-expanded before being passed to `stat`, so names with spaces or glob characters would be prone to surprising behavior.

Comment: @Sam, quite a bit. If your argument is `-n` or `-e`, it's silently eaten. And if you don't know if the bash `xpg_echo` flag is set (which can be done either at runtime or shell compile-time), `echo`'s behavior gets even less predictable

Comment: with `last_modified=$(stat -c %Y "$file")` result is the same as before

Comment: Well, good -- that's what it *should* be (if by "before" you mean "in your original code").

Comment: BTW, consider `if (( (current - last_modified) > 86400 )); then` -- if you're using a `#!/bin/bash` shebang, might as well use bash syntax where it makes your code easier to read.